# Stationary Distribution Markov Chain (Trying to Solve Recursion, Calculation).

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

So I've set up the following equations for this queueing problem (discrete-time Markov chain) to solve for the stationary distribution. First off, I'm not sure if I'm equations are correct. I'm trying to solve for the stationary distribution $\pi$. So I want to solve for $\pi =\pi P$. The state space is countably infinite: $0,1,2,...$
Here are the transition probabilities:

$P_{00}=(1-\lambda)+\lambda(\mu)$

$P_{01}=\lambda(1-\mu)$

For $i \geq 1$

$P_{ii}=\lambda\mu+(1-\mu)(1-\lambda)$

$P_{i,i-1}=(1-\lambda)\mu$

$P_{i,i+1}=\lambda(1-\mu)$

I want to solve for the stationary distribution $\pi$. I thus set up $\pi=\pi P$.
I get:
$\pi_0=[(1-\lambda)+\lambda \mu]\pi_0+[\lambda(1-\mu)]\pi_1$

$\pi_1=[(1-\lambda)\mu]\pi_0+[\lambda(\mu)+(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)]\pi_1+[\lambda(1-\mu)]\pi_2$

$\pi_2=[(1-\lambda)\mu]\pi_1+[\lambda(\mu)+(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)]\pi_2+[\lambda(1-\mu)]\pi_3$

...

....
And I know $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \pi_i=1$

First off, please let me know if these equations are correct. However, my main problem is I have no idea how to solve these equations for a general form for $\pi_i$; I have no idea how to solve these equations to get a general equation for $\pi_{i}$. I tried substituting but its almost impossible me for to get an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a birth-death process, so we may instead use the detailed balance equations
$$
\lambda(1-\mu)\pi_{n-1} = (1-\lambda)\mu \pi_n,\quad n\geqslant 1.
$$
This yields the recurrence
$$
\pi_n = \left(\frac{\lambda(1-\mu)}{\mu(1-\lambda)}\right)^n\pi_0,\quad n\geqslant 0.
$$
Now, assuming that $\frac{\lambda(1-\mu)}{\mu(1-\lambda)}<1$, we have convergence of the following series which gives us the value of $\pi_0$:
$$
1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\lambda(1-\mu)}{\mu(1-\lambda)}\right)^n\pi_0\implies \pi_0 = \frac{\mu-\lambda}{\mu(1-\lambda)}.
$$
Plugging this into the recurrence gives us
$$
\pi_n = \left(\frac{\lambda(1-\mu)}{\mu(1-\lambda)}\right)^n\frac{\mu-\lambda}{\mu(1-\lambda)}.
$$